# Getting exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError wgile reading the excel file in java using poi v4.1.2

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;


public class JavaApplication1 {

    private static Workbook wb;
    private static Sheet sh;
    private static FileInputStream fis;
    private static FileOutputStream fos;
    private static Row row;
    private static Cell cell;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        fis = new FileInputStream("3.xlsx");
        wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
        int noOfRows = sh.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println(noOfRows);
    }

}
```

i am getting this exception while i want to read excel file and print no. of rows

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:307)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:146)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:221)
    at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
D:\Users\vipul\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1330: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Users\vipul\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:936: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: Try adding all the required dependencies - see http://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components or your favourite package manager, then have another go?

Comment: 1. How do you start your application? Are you running it with just a command from the terminal, or are you just clicking something in your IDE? 2. How did you add the POI dependencies? Are you using maven or gradle? If so, please post the contents of pom.xml or build.gradle